# Scheduling Jobs with JobScheduler in Android

Tags: android, task, scheduling, jobs, android-jobscheduler

I have a problem with jobs schedules with JobScheduler in new Android API 21.
This is the code what I schedule the job with 60 seconds interval like below:

```
ComponentName serviceName = new ComponentName(this, MyJobService.class);
JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(0, serviceName)
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPeriodic(60000)
        .build();
```

My JobService only print the time of runtime in Logcat, but the log show that service run in this moments:

```
03-18 08:37:26.334: I/JOB(32662): Wed Mar 18 08:37:26 BRT 2015
03-18 08:37:56.364: I/JOB(32662): Wed Mar 18 08:37:56 BRT 2015
03-18 08:39:21.418: I/JOB(32662): Wed Mar 18 08:39:21 BRT 2015
03-18 08:41:51.670: I/JOB(32662): Wed Mar 18 08:41:51 BRT 2015
03-18 08:45:52.192: I/JOB(32662): Wed Mar 18 08:45:52 BRT 2015
03-18 08:54:20.678: I/JOB(32662): Wed Mar 18 08:54:20 BRT 2015
```

It's strange because the Job it should execute at least 1 time within 1 minute as I set with setPeriodic(60000) method.
It is also curious how the interval increases between runs. At this moment the time is Wed Mar 18 09:09:00 BRT 2015 and the Job don't be executed more.

Is it a problem with JobScheduler API? (I'm running in Nexus 5 with Android 5.0.1)

Answer (score 9):

The time changing has to do with the Back-off Criteria for retrying jobs. By default it is set to exponential. I'm guessing that your also not correctly finishing your job when your done with it by calling `jobFinished(JobParameters params, boolean needsReschedule)`.

I wrote a [blog post](http://toastdroid.com/2015/02/21/how-to-use-androids-job-scheduler/) which focus' on all of the little things with the JobScheduler. I highly recommend reading it.

Comment: Job Scheduler woks perfectly but if i lock the screen the time interval changes continuosly any solution to this which works for me

Comment: One thing the Job Scheduler doesn't do well is ensure exact times for your job to run. I think this would be a case of working as intended. By playing with your params you might be able to fix it though.

Technically now you should use WorkManager instead. There was a Google IO talk on it a couple weeks ago.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IrKoBFLwTN0
https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkManager

Comment: I have tried that, Issue is Work manager allows perodic Jobs 15 mins interval, I have to run job for every 60 seconds any other way i could achieve the result with exact Time frame, I have posted a question could you please ellobrate how to do it with out time lag https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50753823/android-i-am-facing-issue-while-setting-timertask-perodic-interval-when-app-is

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and I think it might be connected with the internal requirements of JobInfo class:

[Source code for JobInfo](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/app/job/JobInfo.java)

```
    /* Minimum interval for a periodic job, in milliseconds. */
private static final long MIN_PERIOD_MILLIS = 15 * 60 * 1000L;   // 15 minutes
```

It looks like JobInfo won't allow you to put interval smaller than that.

Answer (score 1):

//Below are the code I am using in my one of the project and it is working fine for me.

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public void scheduleJob(Context context) {
        //https://kb.sos-berlin.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=3638048
        //Scheduler uses UTC times for all its internal operations. This ensures a continual flow of operation without breaks or repetitions regardless of any changes in local time.
        JobInfo.Builder builder = new JobInfo.Builder(JOB_ID, new ComponentName(context, MyService.class));//JobSchedulerService.class.getName()));
        builder.setPersisted(true); //persist across device reboots

        builder.setPeriodic((120 * 60 * 1000)); //run once after 2 hours seconds

        builder.setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY); // only if wifi avaiblable so they are not using bandwith
        builder.setRequiresDeviceIdle(false); // run not only if the device is idle
        builder.setRequiresCharging(false); // run not only if the device is charging

       // android.os.PersistableBundle bundle = new android.os.PersistableBundle();
        // bundle.putString(WEB_SERVICE_URL, "http://example.com?upload.php");
        //   builder.setExtras(bundle);

        //builder.setBackoffCriteria(1600, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR);
        //BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR After one failure retry at 1 * your value, then at 2 * (your value), then 3 * (your value) and so on
        //BACKOFF_POLICY_EXPONENTIAL After one failure retry at your value, then at (your value)^2, (your value)^3 and so on
        //builder.setMinimumLatency(5 * 1000); //latency
        //builder.setOverrideDeadline(50 * 1000); //wait for criteria to be met, in 50 seconds if they have not then run anyways


        int test = jobScheduler.schedule(builder.build());
        if (test <= 0) {
            Utility.showDialog(context, "Service Error", "Service is not responding");
            //If something goes wrong
        }
    }
```

> We have defined service class per instructed below:

```
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MyService extends JobService {

    @Override
    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    public boolean onStartJob(final JobParameters params) {

        Log.e(TAG, "onStartJob");

        String month = "3";
        String year = "2018";           
MyAsync myAsync = new MyAsync(MyService.this, arraydata, month, year, new SyncAsyncListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataSuccess() {
                        try {
                            jobFinished(params, result);
                        } catch (Exception e) {

                        }
                    }
                });

                myAsync.execute();
            }
    return result;
}
@Override
public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
    return false;
}
}
```