# Android - Timer not running in perodic intervals when app is in locked or sleep state

Tags: android, timer, timertask

In my android project I have periodic task to update API for every 60 seconds for that i am using TimerTask everything is working fine when app is in background or foreground when app is in locked state or sleep state timer milliseconds is lagging every minute, such as first api timing is 10.00.**00** second api timing is 10.01.**05** for every count milliseconds is getting increased

I have tried Work Manager but my perodic interval is 60 Sec,I need an answer which runs perodic Jobs for every 60 Sec without any time lag

I refered this code https://github.com/codexpedia/android_sync_adapter its working fine I have one more issue in SyncAdapter, Some devices Sync Adapter skips Eg: - If I set 60 Sec interval it skips 1 min for every 5 mins could you help me

If app is in doze mode any other solution which works for 7 & 8 api version

Comment: Sync adapter is meant for this

Comment: Thanks I will check & update

Comment: refer the official docs along with example --> https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter

Comment: Thanks Its working fine glad you helped me at right time

Comment: ok let me post it as an answer you can accept it so that it helps others like you

Comment: Done posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your requirement is to sync the data between app and server you can use the **native feature of Android** called **`SyncAdapter`**, this will sync the data either way based on a time interval. You can read about it here in the [docs](http://%20developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/). I would suggest this approach instead of TimerTask.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I have one more issue in SyncAdapter, Some devices Sync Adapter skips Eg: - If I set 60 Sec interval it skips 1 min for every 5 mins could you help me

Comment: Which os  can you tell me, as it might be something like doze mode or some other os optimization

Comment: No,API version is 6.0 but it skips Minute,any other modification need to do for avoiding that

Comment: Can you post your code, and also check if there is any battery saver settings on that device

Comment: I have updated my question provide me suggestion to work in such versions